# How can I set ENVIRONMENT status in Azure DevOps yaml pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml

I am creating CICD pipeline in Azure Devops.

I have pipeline that has name set dynamically.

```
name: 'Set dynamically below in a task'
```

Then in BUILD stage I update it

```
[string] $date = (Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMdd')
[string] $projectVersion = (Get-Content 'version.json') -join "`n" | ConvertFrom-Json | Select -ExpandProperty "version"      
[string] $buildName = "$projectVersion.$(Build.BuildId)+$date.API"     
Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$buildName"
```

I have currently 3 stages

1. Build

   - builds up
   - set build name via VSO command
   - publish artifact
2. Deploy to DEV

   - download artifact and deploy to dev environment
3. Deploy to TEST

   - download artifact and deploy to test environment

I am actually using ENVIRONMENT within Azure Devops to track all deployments and here is the problem. While pipeline build number is updated properly in Pipelines view

[image: Pipelines view]

when I go to Environments tab the not so updated build name is being displayed.

[image: Pipeline view]

How can I change that ?

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue, did you find a solution ?

Comment: I've the same issue too, you found a solution ?

Answer (score -2):

You can set between different environments, such as

```
FIRSTENVIRONMENT
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=VAR1;isOutput=true;]$VALUE";

SECONDENVIRONEMENT
- job: ‘JOBNAME’
       variables:
         var2: $[ dependencies.Build.outputs[Firstenvironment.VAR1] ]
```

Comment: the issue is not passing variables between stages. but how to update deployment stage name because doing the same task for deployment job doesn't do the job

  jobs:
  - deployment: DeployToDev    

and then in runOnce stragey steps I do the same vso[build.updatenumber] .... 

it is not reflected in ENVIRONMENTS status pane